# WP admin bar my account wrong link

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, hyperlink

Right now the href of the link of my member name on the admin bar is empty. I would like to use a custom link when clicked.

So far I have tried all the possible solution even on function.php and the only kind of working is using `jQuery` like:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.ab-item").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
    })
})(jQuery);
```

This works but it changes the link of the notification button instead of the member name.

Please have at look at the pic to understand what I mean:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of WP are you using?

Comment: running WordPress 4.1.1